# CRUD with nextjs using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, next.js

I am trying to perform a delete function on my nextjs app using mongoose, I was able a successfully achieve POST, GET method but still find it difficult to achieve the delete operation.

My POST method inside in API folder:

```js
export default async function addUser(req, res) {
 const data = req.body
 await connectDB()
 const myDocument = await userModel.create(data)
 res.json({ myDocument })
}
```

Here is how I called it from my frontend:

```js
async function Login(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  const userObject = {
    user_name: userName,
    password: password
  }

  const response = await fetch('/api/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(userObject),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })

  const data = await response.json()
  console.log(data)
}
```

I was able to read it using this method and parse the data through props and map through:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  await connectDB()

  const myDocument = await userModel.find()

  return {
    props: {
      myDocument: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myDocument))
    }
  }
}
```

How do perform the DELETE method?

I tried this:

```js
export default async function Remove(req, res) {
  await connectDB()
  await userModel.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    res.send("Deleted")
  })
}
```

which is normally what will work using my node and express, But is not working here.

Here is the frontend function I tried:

```js
function Delete(_id) {
  fetch(`/api/remove/${_id}`)
    .then(() => {
      window.location.reload()
    })
}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long study, I was able to come up with a solution.
I created a dynamic route in my "API" folder called "[id].js" and wrote the following code:

```
export default async (req, res) => {
const {query: {id}} = req
await connectDB()
const deletedUser = await userModel.findByIdAndDelete(id)
if (!deletedUser) return res.status(404).json({msg: "does not exist"})
return res.status(200).json()}
```

I edited my front-end to be:

```
async function Delete(_id) {
    await fetch(`/api/${_id}`, {
        method: 'DELETE'
    }).then(() => {
        //Do something here
    })
}
```